# Get Future RELATIVE Specific Time Based On User Local Time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a bit of a dilemma that I don't know how to tackle and would love it if you guys can help me out.

I want to create a webinar registration page, but have it be in the future at a specific time based on the user local time.

For example:

If `$currentTime` is `4/02/2017 5:00PM PST` for the user, I would like to give the user the ability to see two available dates: `4/05/2017 8:00PM PST` & `4/06/2017 10:00AM PST`

But if `$currentTime` is `4/02/2017 9:00PM` (past the webinar time), I would like the user to see `4/06/2016 10:00 AM` & `4/06/2017 8:00PM`. Basically +3 Days at 8:00 PM and at 10:00 PM everyday.

I would then like to store that value in UTC time into a mysqli server.

I know it's going to involve both PHP and Javascript and some time zone conversions.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi Adam, I had a previous code working, but it only worked on my local time zone (PST). 

I'm currently working on it as we speak. I'll update with full code once I have it available. But so far, I think the logic is going to go like this:
1.) Get User Current Local Time -> 2.) Switch Function to determine offset -> 3.) Display Offset To User -> 4.) POST Time and re-direct upon submit -> 5.) Convert POST Time to UTC (not sure how) -> 6.) strtotime() conversion in PHP and store in database